# What is the difference between nego, ignoro, and nescio?

Tags: etymology, meaning, word-comparison, semantics

Trying to understand the subtle differences between the three words "nego", "ignoro", and "nescio".
This question is not about the meanings in modern English, but the original meanings of the underlying Latin words.

Would this be correct?

**nego**: know but pretend the opposite ?
**ignoro**: should know but don't
**nescio**: could not know

Comment: Unfortunately, what the words *used* to mean may not have any bearing on what they *do* mean now. See "nice", which used to be a negative word, and "awful", which used to be positive. Is your question specifically about the Latin meanings?

Comment: I didn't know for "nice" and "awful", thanks for the information. Yes my question is specifically about the Latin meanings.

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier As your question is specifically about the Latin meanings, I took the liberty to rephrase it to emphasize Latin. Feel free to make further edits if you see fit.

Comment: I would suggest rephrasing the question to ask something like, "What is the difference between nego, ignoro, and nescio?" As it stands, the question's premise is a little shaky (cf. [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy)) and the glosses of the English words are problematic (e.g. "I deny any involvement" doesn't mean "I refuse to know that I was involved.").